# How should I interpret this Post-Probation Situation?

Tags: termination, probation

My boss extended my probationary period, and told me that she is convinced I won't make it during the next probation and I am most likely going to be let go.

Hence, work started to get better as I finished some tasks, and since a couple of weeks, she changed and my workload diminished.

I faced her this morning and asked her how is my probation going, and she replied "nothing has changed, have you started looking for a new job?"

I said "no, not yet", and she replied "well, good luck" and left.

I am not sure why she didn't terminate my contract abruptly, while she involved her boss in what I would call it a dummy project a month before announcing the extension of my probation.

Why didn't she just terminate my job, simply?

Comment: Only your boss can answer this. Take her advice to heart and start looking; it's very very difficult to overcome such an environment and history.

Comment: +1 @user1008090 Don't worry about why your boss acts this way, just take advantage of the fact you're getting paid while you job hunt.

Comment: In case it's not clear: You should be looking for a new job. There's a good chance that you'll be fired, and even if you're not, it's going to be a bad working environment.

Answer (score 2):

> Why didn't she just terminate my job, simply?

We can never know. Your question is opinion-based, but I think that all opinions will agree that you should find another job.

I have a feeling that she extended your probation to help you transition without gaps in your resume(while you are making money). I would not mention her on my resume though.

You should have asked her `why probation extension?` right then and there when she said `"well, good luck"`, but the answer is just for curiosity really and won't change things, as she said too.